# use accumulative recursion to find longest win in drracket

Tags: racket

Assume `(list 'win 'loss 'win 'win 'win 'loss 'win 'win)` and produce the longest win which is 3. using accumulative recursion.  what i did is as follows:

```
(define (fun list)
  (local
    [(define (helper los accu1 accu2)
       (cond
         [(empty? los) (length accu2)]
         [else
          (cond
            [(equal? (first los) 'loss)
             (helper (rest los) 0 accu2)]
            [else
             (helper (rest los) 0 (cons (first los) accu2))])]))]
    (helper list empty empty)))
```

the problem is i don't know what to do when i got a loss in the list,my function only calculates all the win instead of the longest win.someone help please :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you intended:

```
(define (fun lst)
  (define (helper lst current longest)
    (cond
      [(empty? lst)              (max current longest)]
      [(equal? (first lst) 'win) (helper (rest lst) (add1 current) longest)]
      [else                      (helper (rest lst) 0 (max current longest))]))
  (helper lst 0 0))
```

then

```
> (fun (list 'win 'loss 'win 'win 'win 'loss 'win 'win))
3
```

The point is that you need **2** variables; one for the number of *current* consecutive `'win` symbols, and one for the *previously* highest consecutive number. There's no need to create intermediate lists, counters are sufficient.